# Using MySQL MATCH for mix of column types in non-case-sensitive

Tags: mysql

I am using a MATCH condition to match against a int field and a varchar field. According to http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22343 when mixing binary and non-binary column types the match becomes binary and thus case sensitive.

My question is how would I go about making the search non-case-sensitive? I have tried using MATCH (lower(a),b) AGAINST ('title') but this does not work.

Here is a schema that can be used as a test.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo` (
  `a` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `b` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `foo` (`a`, `b`) VALUES
(2345345, 'title and volume'),
(145344, 'Volume'),
(1234214, 'Title');

SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE MATCH (a,b) AGAINST ('title' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you'd have to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM `foo`
WHERE MATCH(`a`) AGAINST ('title' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR MATCH(`b`) AGAINST ('title' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: That throws a syntax error. Similar to when I tried to do LOWER(a)

Comment: That's irritating.  I guess you have to break up the `MATCH` then.

Comment: I read before that breaking up the match would work. In my test with the above it is still case sensitive which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Bizarre.  Sounds like another bug to me.